# how to apply a sequence of conditions to np.where()

Tags: python, numpy

I need to count the mean of indices of the same elements from np.array

I've tried map and list comprehension with np.where function but they return python list that I need to convert back to np.like.
   And unfortunately can't find something appropriate from numpy by myself, and don't know numpy very good

there is an example of what I tried to do

```py
A = np.array ([2,5,9,8,8,3,2,1,2,1,8])
set_ = np.unique(A)
indeces = [np.where(A==i) for i in set_]
mean_ = [np.mean(i) for i in indeces]
```

but list comprehension gives out a list while np.where - ndarray
i would like to use numpy without unnecessarily convert

I tried to use map and np.fromiter like:

```py
indeces = map(np.where,[A==i for i in set_])
mean_ = np.fromiter(indeces,dtype = np.int)
```

but it's provide an:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```py
mean_ = [8.0, 4.666666666666667, 5.0, 1.0, 5.666666666666667, 2.0]
```

with the code above, but pls can anyone suggests an efficient way to do this pure with numpy or closest.
Thanks for attention )

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your desired output for your given input?

Comment: can you provide an example of what would the output or final result should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in `A` are non-negative integers, you could perform the calculation with two calls to `np.bincount`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array ([2,5,9,8,8,3,2,1,2,1,8])
result = np.bincount(A, weights=np.arange(len(A))) / np.bincount(A)
result = result[~np.isnan(result)]
print(result)
```

yields

```
[8.         4.66666667 5.         1.         5.66666667 2.        ]
```

If `A` contains arbitrary values, you could first convert the values to non-negative integer labels, and then proceed as above:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array ([2,5,9,8,8,3,2,1,2,1,8])+0.5
uniqs, B = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)
result = np.bincount(B, weights=np.arange(len(B))) / np.bincount(B)
result = result[~np.isnan(result)]
print(result)
```

yields

```
[8.         4.66666667 5.         1.         5.66666667 2.        ]
```

---

How it works: [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) counts how many times each value in an array of non-negative ints occurs:

```
In [161]: np.bincount(A)
Out[161]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1])
                    |  |                 |  |
                    |  |                 |  o--- 9 occurs once
                    |  |                 o--- 8 occurs three times
                    |  o--- 2 occurs three times                       
                    o--- 1 occurs twice
```

If a `weight` parameter is provided, then instead of counting occurrences by 1, it increases the count by `weight`:

```
In [162]: np.bincount(A, weights=np.arange(len(A)))
Out[163]: array([ 0., 16., 14.,  5.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0., 17.,  2.])
                      |    |                             |     |
                      |    |                             |     o--- 9 occurs at index 2
                      |    |                             o--- 8 occurs at indices (3,4,10)
                      |    o--- 2 occurs at indices (0,6,8)
                      o--- 1 occurs at indices (7,9)
```

Since `np.arange(len(A))` equals the index value for each item in `A`, the above call to `np.bincount` sums the indices for each value in `A`.
Dividing the two arrays returned by `np.bincount` gives the mean index values.

---

Alternatively, using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), the calculation can be expressed as a [`groupby/mean` operation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A = np.array([2,5,9,8,8,3,2,1,2,1,8])
S = pd.Series(np.arange(len(A)))
print(S.groupby(A).mean().values)
```

yields

```
[8.         4.66666667 5.         1.         5.66666667 2.        ]
```

Comment: Nice... But it will crash your OS if A contains a large integer like 1e9. Moreover, the solution return bad answer for nonintegers in A